# Undirected graph on disk

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

What is the most efficient way to process un-directed graphs from disk.

I have the following problem statement -
For every person entity `X`,I have information on all person entities `Y1,Y2,Y3....` who are friends of X.
I would need to find all person entities who are friends of `Y1,Y2,Y3.....`but not a friend of X.

This can be represented as an undirected graph in memory.

However,given that the edges that need to be loaded for this issue is potentially very large;and so is the number of similar requests that the server is tolerating at a  given time - how do we process this problem with secondary storage?

Any suggestions or write-up are appreciated.

Comment: Am I understand your problem correct, you want to find every friend of friends of X who is not friend of X? like x friend with y and y is friend of z but x and z is not friend. am I right?

Comment: Correct.And this search has to happen for every friend of X.

Comment: How can there be an infinite amount of friend edges?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier there could be infinite (or very large)amount of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

For doing that you could simply use two steps of `BFS`:

- Start from your node `X` and load all the edges from `X` visit its every neighbor put them in a list and mark them visited.
- created list and call it `friends of friends`
- for every node in the visited list:

  - load its edges, visit its neighbors:
  - for every node that you visited if it was not marked visited before put it in the `friends of friends` list, and mark the node visited.
  - unload the edges that you loaded for this node.

please let me know if there is any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to store the list of friends in sorted order  (e.g. sort by id).

Then to find the answer for a person X you construct a FIFO for each friend Y of X.

The algorithm will then work along these lines:

1. Read the first person from each Y FIFO and keep track of the largest id seen (M)
2. Keep reading elements from each Y FIFO if the id is smaller than M, and update M if the id is larger.  If id matches M then move onto the next fifo.
3. If a fifo becomes empty, then we are finished.
4. If we have inspected all the fifos without increasing M, then we stop the loop (we have found something to output)

If this process stops without emptying a fifo, we know we have found a person M who is in all of the Y friend lists.

If this person is not a friend of X, then output M.

Next increase M by 1, and go back to step 2.

Note that the FIFOs are not reset when you return to step 2, so this process will only read through each Y FIFO once.

You will need to have enough memory to store the position in each Y FIFO.
If the lists are stored on disk, you may wish to read several entries in a single disk access to improve performance.